# canOpenURL error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, info.plist

Here is my canOpenURL function call:

```
@IBAction func likeButtonDidClick(_ sender: Any) {
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/app/id1198074300") as! URL)
}
```

I am getting an error when trying to use canOpenURL in Swift.

[image]

Here is my info.plist

[image]

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>itms</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: @matt Edited to show the function call

Comment: @matt My bad lol. I tried the guy's fix below but it didn't do anything. Should be updated now.

Comment: Do you want to open the app store? In that case, the URL should begin with `itms-apps://`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple fix with this code segment

```
@IBAction func likeButtonDidClick(_ sender: Any) {
    openStoreProductWithiTunesItemIdentifier(identifier: "1198074300")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That error message seems to occur when the app is not installed on the device , if you are running on simulator, try using a actual device, if you are using a actual device and still that error is happening try rebooting your device.

Comment: If you need clarification (*"are you running on the simulator?"*) from the OP, please add a comment to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15434652)

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan hey, i did not have the privilege to comment anywhere till yesterday, now i have that right so'll ask in comments only. :) Thank you for your feedback.